# P2V conversion at 120 ms latency?

Tags: vmware-vcenter

Is it feasible to do P2V at the avg latency of 120 ms between source and target? I am trying to do P2V from London to USA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, plenty of time for coffee breaks but yeah, so long as it's consistent then why not.

Comment: +1, it will be fine, just verrrryyy sloooow

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure that the disk copy parts are block based copies rather than file level copies ( both VMware Converter and Novell's PowerConvert can do block based copying of the disks) then it will probably be much less latency sensitive. If there are lots of small files then a P2V using file level copying will be painfully slow. Bandwidth still matters though and will probably still be the most significant variable you need to consider, a trans-atlantic P2V over a Gagabit-per-sec pipe @ 120ms (with block based copying) should beat a local migration on a <1ms 100Megabit-per-sec LAN.